# Keras custom loss "None" for gradient

Tags: keras

I currently try to create a custom loss function for a keras binary classification model. TP, TN, FP, FN have each a different reduction of profit as the result.

FN reduces profit by 72$
TP reduces profit by 28.2$
TN reduces profit by 0$
FP reduces profit by 5.7$

The current loss function looks like the following, but gives the error stated below.

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    TP = K.all(K.stack([y_true, y_pred], axis=0), axis=0)
    # FP = K.all(K.stack([K.square(tensorflow.subtract(y_true, 1)), y_pred]))
    # FN = K.all(K.stack([y_true, K.square(y_pred-K.constant(1))]))

    return K.sum(K.switch(TP, K.ones_like(y_true), K.zeros_like(y_true))*K.constant(28.2))



ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

I generally understand what the error is about but I don't know how I can model the loss function so that all operations used have a gradient != None

I found various resources on how to model custom loss functions but didn't manage to adapt them to my "fixed cost" function